# Assign MAX value of mysql field to php variable

Tags: php

I want to assign the max value of a column in mysql to a variable in PHP. This ultimately will be to validate form data. Having trouble as I am new to PHP.

Tried this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(receipt_id) FROM receipts");
if (!result) {
trigger_error(mysql_error($result));
}

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$maxid = $row["receipt_id"];

echo "The max id is $row";
```

(The echo is just for testing). In this case the result was:

The max id Array

When I echo the $maxid variable in the above code there is no value returned in the echo.

And with this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(receipt_id) FROM receipts");
if (!result) {
    trigger_error(mysql_error($result));
}

echo "The max id is $result";
```

I get:

The max id is Resource id #2

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Add an alias to the max sql function result:

```
SELECT MAX(receipt_id) AS max_value FROM receipts
```

Access it like any other value:

```
$row["max_value"]
```

Comment: Nice. Here is me kicking myself. Thanks.